# Git client asking password when I try to access first time using SSH Key

Tags: git, ssh

I am using Git to access remote repository and when ever I try to access git using my ssh key, it's asking password. I never added password in any stage. My Git Admin imported my id_rsa.pub file into GIT server and configured. But, with out password it's not proceeding further, also I never succeeded to access git from git client.

Can anyone suggest what could be the issue?

Thank you

Comment: When interacting with a remote git repo through ssh, you need to provide your ssh password, with which you have setup your ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

> I never added password in any stage

The only stage where a "password" (passphrase actually) could have been set is when creating your `id_rsa` private key.

Check if that file begins with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,556C1115CDA822F5
```

If so, you would need to [add that key to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) in order to cache said passphrase.